# Can you change the way numpy prints arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3d, 3x3x3 array of integers.  Numpy will print these as a block of the first 3x3, then below it the 2nd 3x3, then below that the 3rd 3x3.

If I wanted to print these 3 3x3 blocks BESIDE each other, rather than underneath each other, how would I tell numpy to print differently?

Comment: Just write your own printNPArr/strNPArr function.

Answer (score 3):

```
class MyArray(numpy.array):
    def __str__(self):
        print [[[d for d in c] for c in b] for b in a]
```

This essentially subclasses `numpy.array` and just changes the `__str__` function (which is called when getting the string representation of an object) which converts it into a regular array and prints that.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to explain what you are doing... Teach a man to fish and all that.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np   
arr=np.random.random((3,3,3))    
print(arr)
# [[[ 0.05733376  0.00646892  0.96180769]
#   [ 0.11560363  0.56058966  0.83942817]
#   [ 0.5520361   0.17355794  0.87699437]]

#  [[ 0.90999361  0.03036473  0.5064459 ]
#   [ 0.76169531  0.48234618  0.56884999]
#   [ 0.93220906  0.9460365   0.65307273]]

#  [[ 0.04400683  0.58783221  0.74281147]
#   [ 0.69999475  0.14870245  0.32175415]
#   [ 0.20044376  0.11985585  0.69949965]]]

for rows in zip(*arr):
    print('\t'.join(map(str,rows)))
# [ 0.05733376  0.00646892  0.96180769] [ 0.90999361  0.03036473  0.5064459 ]   [ 0.04400683  0.58783221  0.74281147]
# [ 0.11560363  0.56058966  0.83942817] [ 0.76169531  0.48234618  0.56884999]   [ 0.69999475  0.14870245  0.32175415]
# [ 0.5520361   0.17355794  0.87699437] [ 0.93220906  0.9460365   0.65307273]   [ 0.20044376  0.11985585  0.69949965]
```

For convenience, you could wrap it in a function:

```
def format_arr(arr):
    result=[]
    for x in zip(*arr):
        result.append('\t'.join(map(str,x)))
    return '\n'.join(result)

print(format_arr(arr))
```